# How can I disable YouCompleteMe and enable NeoComplete, only for one filetype?

Tags: vim, neocomplete

I use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) for auto-completion in Vim. It doesn’t work well together with [VimShell](https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim), so I want to disable it, only within VimShell buffers.

How can I disable YouCompleteMe and enable [NeoComplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) from Vimscript?

Comment: It depends on how you install plugins in your setup (i.e. how you installed YouCompleteMe). Did you install it manually, with Pathogen, with Vundle? For example, if you used [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/), you need to delete `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` from your `vimrc`, and then add a `Plugin` call for NeoComplete.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I use Pathoghen and build YouCompleteMe from source code. and I only want to disable YouCompleteMe for certian filetype.

Answer (score 14):

YouCompleteMe allows you to configure a filetype whitelist and blacklist that enables or disables completion for given filetypes.

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#the-gycm_filetype_whitelist-option

Neocomplete has a similar feature, with `NeoCompleteUnlock`/`NeoCompleteLock`.

https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/290b9532ae3a04b53f0d0ecdee34e2b664229939/doc/neocomplete.txt#L204

For example, to disable YouCompleteMe and enable NeoComplete for the vimshell filetype, you could use something like this in your .vimrc:

```
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = { 'vimshell': 1 }
autocmd FileType vimshell NeoCompleteUnlock
```

I cannot test this, as I do not use vimshell.